# EJS shows red mark when trying to embed data

Tags: node.js, express, visual-studio-code, ejs

i have this node server with express which directs data to different files like .ejs files and it worked before but I dont know what I did and so that it doesnt work, it marks every ejs's "<" in red.
im using VS CODE.

```
    var app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');


app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send("Hello wassup");
});

app.get('/homepage/:name', function(req,res){
    res.render('home', {fullname : req.params.name});
});

app.get('/profile/:name', function(req, res){
    var data = {Dummytext: "hey yo wassup and all that yea imma be right here tho",
        hobbies : ['baskeall','computing','drawing', 'Learning', 'Driving'] };
    res.render('profile', {fullname: req.params.name, data:data});
});

app.listen(4000);
```

and i have for example this ejs file that doesnt work

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>bla</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="partials/nav.css">
</head>
<body>

<% include partials/nav.ejs %>

<div class="user-info">
    <div class="user-about">
        <div class="user-name"><span><%= fullname %></span></div>
        <div class="user-info_">
            <div class="userimg">
            <img src="/YDSign.png" alt="User profile" draggable="false" />
            </div>
            <div class="user-speech"><p><%= data.Dummytext%></p></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="user-button">
        <button type="button" class="friendAdd">Add Friend</button>
        <button type="button" class="friendBell">Bell</button>
    </div>
    <div class="user-hobbies">
        <div class="hobbies-list">
            <h1>Hobbies</h1>
            <div class="Upscroll"><img src="/iconList/ArrowUp.png" draggable="false"/></div>
            <ul>
                <% data.hobbies.forEach(function(item){ %>
                    <li><a><%= item %></a><img src="iconList/Hobbies.png" class="ident" /></li>
                <% }); %>
            </ul>
            <div class="Downscroll"><img src="/iconList/ArrowDown.png" draggable="false" /></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything is fine.

You just should install plugin `EJS language support` in VSCode.
Just click `CTRL+SHIFT+X` and then write `ejs` in the search bar after that install the first one.

That works for me.